# upgrading to specific php version on centos 7

Tags: centos, php, centos7

I am currently running centOS 7 with an apache based webserver with php 5.5.38 and I was recommend to upgrade to PHP 5.6.XX for best stability on behalf of my custom made web-app.

Is there a way to upgrade to this specific PHP version without getting the latest built? Please do not answer with advice on how the latest built is the best and most recommended, I am looking for a solution to upgrade to an exact version.

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: I think a supported  PHP 5.6 is available in the software collections repo, but I don't have a CentOS 7 system available at the moment https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple versions of PHP are available in the [SCL Repos](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php56/) but if you're looking for a very specific version of PHP, you might want to check the repos [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/rh-php56/) to see if your build is available.

If it's not, you may have to package up the version of PHP you want into an RPM, or install it manually. There's an [example spec file in the PHP github repo](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/makerpm)